# Possible to observe network status?

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm wondering if there's a way to somehow register as an observer for network access (and have some callback function run when the internet is avaliable), or if polling is the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register receiver:

```
//Callback  
private final BroadcastReceiver mNetworkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           //network state changes, you can process it, inforamtion in intent
        }
    };

//registering recievr in actibity or in service
IntentFilter mNetworkStateFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(mNetworkStateReceiver , mNetworkStateFilter);
```

Detail at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Answer (score 0):

My solution for observing network state, also wifi/cellular data connection can be observed independently:

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
    import android.content.Context
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager
    import android.net.Network
    import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
    import android.net.NetworkRequest
    import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
    import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
    import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob
    import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
    import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharingStarted
    import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow
    import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.combine
    import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.stateIn
    
object InternetConnectionObserver {
    
        private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob())
    
        private val _connectionStateWifi = MutableStateFlow(NetworkState.UNDEFINED)
        val connectionStateWifi = _connectionStateWifi.asStateFlow()
    
        private val _connectionStateCellular = MutableStateFlow(NetworkState.UNDEFINED)
        val connectionStateCellular = _connectionStateCellular.asStateFlow()
    
        val connectionState =
            _connectionStateWifi.combine(_connectionStateCellular) { wifiState, cellularState ->
                if (wifiState == NetworkState.CONNECTED || cellularState == NetworkState.CONNECTED) {
                    NetworkState.CONNECTED
                } else {
                    NetworkState.NOT_CONNECTED
                }
            }.stateIn(scope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, NetworkState.UNDEFINED)
    
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        fun start(context: Context) {
            val connectivityManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ConnectivityManager
            connectivityManager?.let {
                val wifiNetworkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                        super.onAvailable(network)
                        _connectionStateWifi.value = NetworkState.CONNECTED
                    }
    
                    override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                        super.onLost(network)
                        _connectionStateWifi.value = NetworkState.NOT_CONNECTED
                    }
                }
                val cellularNetworkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                        super.onAvailable(network)
                        _connectionStateCellular.value = NetworkState.CONNECTED
                    }
    
                    override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                        super.onLost(network)
                        _connectionStateCellular.value = NetworkState.NOT_CONNECTED
                    }
                }
                val wifiRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED)
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                    .build()
                val cellularRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                    .build()
                connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(wifiRequest, wifiNetworkCallback)
                connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(cellularRequest, cellularNetworkCallback)
            }
        }
    
        fun isConnected(): Boolean = connectionState.value == NetworkState.CONNECTED
    
        fun isWifiConnected() = connectionStateWifi.value == NetworkState.CONNECTED
    
        fun isCellularConnected() = connectionStateCellular.value == NetworkState.CONNECTED
    
        enum class NetworkState {
            CONNECTED, NOT_CONNECTED, UNDEFINED
        }
    }
```